# How to format code similar to the way Vim has (select + "=")?

Tags: text-editing, formatting

In Vim I can format code by the key `=`, with or without selecting a region. Is there a way to do it in Emacs in an easy way too?

Comment: If you use lsp-mode there are the commands `lsp-format-buffer` and `lsp-format-region`

Comment: If you are not against `evil-mode`, it's also `=`.

Comment: You can use aggressive-indent to format as you type

Comment: To just indent the code according to its mode, you can do `C-x h`, ``M-C-\`` (`mark-whole-buffer`, `indent-region`).